# Crystal Report Viewer crashing an application when trying to export the report source to disk as a PDF .Net

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I'm trying to export the reportsource of a crystal report viewer in .Net 1.1 onto disk as a PDF using

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument cr = (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument)crvView.ReportSource;
cr.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.[Shared].ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"C:\Temp\Temp.pdf");
```

I know it's the "cr.ExportToDisk..." line thats failing, but dont know why.
Ive checked to make sure the Crystal Report versions are the same on the client machines and they are.

Sometime i get the message "Memory could not be read at source...." and the application completely crashes, and other times the app crashes without the message.

Any ideas on why this happens and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Are those "sometimes" "always for the same data", "always for the same machine", or "always for the same data, on the same machine", or a genuine case of "given the same input, the same machine will sometimes work, and sometimes fail"?

Comment: Given the same input, different machines will produce different results (fail or succeed). However the same machine with the same data will always produce the same result (if it fails once, it will always fail and vice versa).

Comment: Do these failing machines have an older version of crystal?

Comment: No, ive checked the versions on each of the machines and both the failing machines and the non-failing machines all have the same version of crystal.

Comment: I've seen cases where having multiple versions of crystal installed can give you crazy errors. Is it possible they also have an older version in addition to the correct version?

Comment: I have the same issue and this is also applicable: "given the same input, the same machine will sometimes work, and sometimes fail". Like if it is a bad today, it will be failing every time. If it is a good day, it will work like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You may check to make sure that the security permissions are the same for the locations that you are trying to export to.

Comment: I've tried exporting to several locations on the clients machine with the same result (including locations that i know the client has full priveladges to).

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to print these "faulty" reports? If so, have you tried printing to [CutePdf](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) which might allow you to at least work around the issue temporarily.